# Adobe Analytics - Page name variable does not correctly match url where event is fired

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

When clicking on a button on our page "Verify", the user has the option to click on a link that fires an event with the identifier, "Consumer Verify - Choose Verification Options Button". That is captured in the eVar74. However, our Page Name value is "/pay/method" and the eVar4 is "/pay/method - Consumer Verify - Choose Verification Options Button".

The **actual** data in Adobe is registered as:

Page Name: /pay/method

eVar4: /pay/method - Consumer Verify - Choose Verification Options Button

The **expected** data should be:

Page Name: /pay/verify

eVar4: /pay/verify - Consumer Verify - Choose Verification Options Button

/pay/method is the page that the user is going to, not the page where the event was triggered. Why is the Page Name value not capturing the correct path, (/pay/verify)? What are the potential reasons why this may be happening and where should I look in the configuration to see if the Page Name is set up correctly? This is a SPA Vue app.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the history/pushState change is happening before your AA hit. This is usually a result of using passive event listener hooks in your tag manager (or using vanilla js) because the url/hash gets updated during that event - and then your listener callback is called. Your options for fixing this involve keeping track of the previous page name (e.g. `getPreviousValue` AA plugin or similar in principle) or having the site devs explicitly make a tracking call (e.g. tag manager direct call rule call, `s.t()`,  or similar in principle), explicitly passing a pageName value.

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you.